# NAT routing command in windows

Tags: windows, networking, routing, iptables, nat

Is there any specific command in windows which do the following task:

I want to modify the source IP address in the packet whose Destination IP is not in the private LAN, i.e.,

I have a virtual interface whose IP address id 198.0.0.1/24, and physical ethernet interface(eth0) whose IP is X.X.X.X (Having different subnet then the virtual interface)

Packets of virtual interface having source IP 198.0.0.1 are routed through the eth0,
But They need to be transferred using source IP as X.X.X.x(eth0).

How can I accomplish this in windows ?

In linux it can be done using NAT iptable postrouting rule.